# How to see which radio buttons are clicked Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I have some radio buttons on my page that pop up for users to flag things (below).  Along with the radio buttons is an "other" button with a textarea to write in a different reason.  I would like to be able to see which buttons are pressed when the form is submitted via jquery.  I know how to use .post() but im not sure if should i use .val() on each id of the radio buttons.  Or, is there one check that can check the entire group and get the checked label?   Im pretty sure i can use .val() on the textarea if the other button is pressed.

HTML:

```
<input type='radio' id='spam' name='flagGroup'></input><label for='spam'>It is spam</label><br>
<input type='radio' id='offTopic' name='flagGroup'></input><label for='offTopic'>It is off topic</label><br>
<input type='radio' id='quality' name='flagGroup'></input><label for='quality'>It does not meet quality standards</label><br>
<input type='radio' id='wrongLocation' name='flagGroup'></input><label for='wrongLocation'>It is in the wrong location</label><br>
<input type='radio' id='duplicate' name='flagGroup'></input><label for='duplicate'>There is a duplicate question</label><br>
<input type='radio' id='other' name='flagGroup'></input><label for='other'>Other:</label><br>
<textarea id='flagOtherTextarea' rows='2' cols='40' wrap='soft'></textarea>
<hr />
<input type='radio' id='mod'></input><label for='mod'>It needs moderator attention</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following selector

```
$allChecked = $('input[type="radio"]:checked');
```

If you wanted to get the text of all of the labels after the input you could do the following

```
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function() {
  var label = $(this).next('label');
  alert(label.text());
});
```

Comment: thanks, but would this give me the label values of the radiobuttons or just tell me which ones are checked?

Comment: @user802370 this will return the set of `input` elements that are checked.  You can then dig further into those elements and grab the label for example

Comment: i used an alert on your variable and tried out the code and it returned "[object Object]."

Comment: @user802370 that's because it's a selector.  If you want to see the invidiual objects use `each`.  I'll update my sample to print out the label text for all of the values.

Answer (score 0):

To get selected radio button. But you have to assign value to each to be able to distinguish them

```
   $('input[name=flagGroup]:checked').val()
```

Or if you want to use for attribute use

```
   $('input[name=flagGroup]:checked').attr('for');
```